# Post files using ajax is returning 400 error

Tags: asp.net-ajax, multipartform-data, razor-pages

I'm trying to do a file upload in a razor page web app. But it's returning 400 error. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
<input type="submit" onclick="return showUploadResult()">
```

Javascript:

```
function showUploadResult() {
    var files = $('#myFile').prop("files");
    var url = "/Index?handler=UploadCustomerSuccessBonus";
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("CustomerSuccessBonus", files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfToken()' },
        success: function () {

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error occurs");
        }
    });
}
```

Page:

```
        public IActionResult OnPostUploadCustomerSuccessBonus(IFormFile CustomerSuccessBonus)
        {

            return Page();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as-is when passing a valid token value to the `RequestVerificationToken` so it looks like your `GetAntiXsrfToken()` method is not doing what you expect.

Comment: Thank you!

I use this token in all other ajax calls and they all work...

Comment: Ok I was dumb. You are right! The @GetAntiXsrfToken() was working in razor page, but I moved this code to site.js so the razor @ wouldn't work anymore here! Moved this code back to the razor page and everything works now!